# Uniform convergence of f(x/n) to f(o)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying the following problem:

[image]

the solution feels wrong to me since I don't think it deals with a situation in which f can drive to infinity around some point in [a,b].

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Your actual problem is, imo, with the line just before the last one: "let N be such that..." , as this line gives you the last one, which is certainly the proof of uniform convergence....but there is no problem at all in this line, either, as you can *really* find such an $\;N\;$ because $\;[a,b]\;$ is bounded!

Observe that you fear that $\;f\;$ can "drive to infinity" around any point at all is unfounded, as it is given that $\;f\;$ is **defined** at any point

Comment: Mm I see, so would you say the proof  is complete as it is?

Comment: @OL Yes, indeed.